# Similarity between Salut in French and Salaam in Arabic

Tags: french, arabic

I noticed a similarity between the word ***Salut*** in French and the word ***سلام*** in Arabic which is pronounced ***Salaam*** and they both mean "safety and well-being" and are both used as a general greeting to mean "hello". But Salut comes from Latin which I don't think is related to Arabic in any way. How can that be possible then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like you said, the French term **salut** comes from Latin and to be precise from *salūs salūtis*. This term appears in other Romance Languages as well: *It*. saluto, *Es.* saludo.

The meaning which is *health, well-being*, is carried out also by other descendants: *It.* salute, *Es.* salud, *Port.* saúde.

I don't think there is a connection to **salaam** which actually means *peace* in Arabic (I think you can confirm this meaning) and is related to the term **shalom** in Hebrew. You can find more about this on the Wikipedia page for **Shin-Lamedh-Mem**, the *"the triconsonantal root of many Semitic words"*, at the section [Salam "Peace"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A0-L-M#Salam_.22Peace.22).

According to the same page, this *"root itself translates as whole, safe, intact"*, but the triconsonantal part refers to the Š-L-M, while in salut we miss the last one and we have a T instead.

There seems to be a real closeness in terms of meanings which could be a coincidence. Still, this is just a superficial analysis and I don't have all the tools/resources to absolutely exclude a link.

Comment: Generally, given the number of words in any language, and the number of combinations of sounds they represent, and barring borrowings, **any** two languages that are not related will have at least two or three words that are close to identical in sound, with close to identical meanings, by chance alone. Exempli gratia: English _hole_ vs Yukatek Maya _ho:l_ 'hole'; and Latin _dua_ vs Malay _duwa_ '2'.

Comment: @jlawler Yes that's true. I didn't exclude the coincidence and to me there's no link but I didn't want to be too strict with the judgement. :)

Comment: I think the triconsonantal root thingy is evidence enough that it is mostly a coincidence. The only possibility I see is later developments when Arabs started speaking Latin to some degree and some sort of cross-pollination occurred that influenced the development of the Arab word and its pronunciation to some minor degree.

Comment: @jlawler Malay has borrowed a lot from Sanskrit and Persian so you can't tell that the similarity between _dua_ and _duwa_ is a pure concidence (Because Persian and Sanskrit are related to European languages)

Comment: @MohammadSanei: Malays, since they already had a maritime technological culture when Islam reached them, did not borrow as many technological words as other Muslim cultures. And it's very rare for languages to borrow basic words like 'two'; in fact, Malay _duwa_ comes from Proto-Austronesian _*dalawa_ by regular processes of syllable elision. You can see what I mean in [this problem](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/LangRelations.pdf); Malay is Column "E".

Comment: @Alenanno Don't you think there's a relationship between the German word "Hallo" from which "Hello" has been derived, and the word Salut (or Salus in Latin)? I believe there's a chance of the sound 'h' having been mutated into 's' or vice versa.

Comment: What does this answer add? It is evident it is from Latin. Three-consonant root is a Semitic innovation and was not present in Proto-Afro-Asiatic.

Comment: @Mohammad Sanei no, Hello is not related to heal, Hi, German Heil. Still Heil and heal are related to Russian целый "whole", and to a PIE qoilos. This is not related to solu̯os from which Salute is derived.

Comment: @Anixx What about Hallo? I mean could there be a relationship between the German word "Hallo" and the Latin word "Salus"?

Comment: @Cerberus tri-consonantal roots is a proto-Semitic innovation which was not present in Proto-Afro-Asiatic.

Comment: @Mohammad Sanei Oxford English Dictionary links it to French la "there", possibly from Latin illa "that" (feminine).

Comment: More exactly, health and whole are related to PIE qoa̯ilus.

Comment: @Anixx What repetition do you see exactly? I've said more than he stated in his question.

Comment: @Anixx Your answer was ingenious and extremely useful. Actually, it was the only answer that I upvoted. But I had to make a really difficult choice so I decided to go for the more skeptic and conservative view which was Alenanno's.

Comment: @jlawler: Persian for “four” is čæhɒr چهار, not “čæhær”.

Comment: In French, it has also the meaning of "salvation, and "peace": Que le salut soit sur toi.

Answer (score 5):

These words **may** be related.

The Latin word comes from Proto-Indo-European ***solu̯os*** "healthy, whole". It is hypotized to derive from Proto-Eurasiatic ***calom*** "to suffice, be full" which also gave reflexes in other Eurasiatic languages such as Eskimo-Aleut ***ciɫǝ-m***, Altaic ***čā́lo***, Uralic ***cilä***, Dravidian ***sāl-***

The Arabic ***salaam*** and Hebrew ***šalom*** both derive from Proto-Semitic  ***šǝlǝm*** "healthy, whole", which in turn derives from Proto-Afro-Asiatic ***s/cǝlǝm*** "healthy, whole".

Since both Eurasiatic and Afro-Asiatic belong to Nostratic (and considered quite close to each other), it is reasonable to suppose they are related.

Notice also Proto-Sino-Caucasian ***ʒó̆ɫǝ*** "healthy, whole" (example from Lak language: ***cullu-s:a*** "whole, healthy, undamaged") with Proto-Sino-Caucasian groupped as sister family to Nostratic into Borean.

Comment: Though it should be noted that most comparative linguists don't accept all these reconstructions. Proto-Indo-European is well-established, but this is not the case for (Proto- or non-Proto-) Eurasiatic, Sino-Caucasian, or Nostratic. There are even lots of linguists who don't accept Altaic; more than there used to be, in fact. The comparative method provides a limited window for temporal reconstruction; more than about 4 or 5 Kiloyears back, things get very, very muddy.

Comment: @jlawler 5 kiloyears back the things are quite clear, the difficulties start deeper in the past.

Comment: @jlawler the majority of linguists accept either Eurasiatic or Nostratic groupping in the sense they agree that the languages which constitute them are closely related.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous posts,
"Salve" was a common greeting phrase in Sweden during the medieval time,
and also has a similar meaning (peace, well-being).

Comment: That is probably related to the words I mentioned, at least to the word Salut.

Comment: I realize this is 6 years old, but someone bumped this question to the front page, so… Medieval Swedish "salve" was borrowed directly from Danish usage, which borrowed it from French, which inherited it from Latin, where it's the imperative of "salveō", meaning "be healthy!" French "salut" comes from Latin "salvus". And "salvus" is possibly derived from "salveō + -vus" in Latin, more likely from a proto-Italic coinage, or possibly all the way back to PIE "solh₂- + -wós". So yes, they're related.